# ADF v2: Define keys for upsert behavior

Tags: dynamics-crm, etl, azure-data-factory, upsert

I'm trying to create a copy activity that copies from SQL to Dynamics CRM. I'm using the ADF v2 default connector. The Dynamics connectors as a sink have the upsert behavior but I don't know how to define the keys for comparing in the upsert. If I complete the configuration and the mapping, removing the unnecessary columns and I run the activity, I have the following error: `Input DataSet must contain key column(s) in Upsert/Update scenario. Missing key column(s):` Is there any way to set the keys in the input dataset? My mapping looks like:

[image]

This field is always empty: 
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify it manually? No selections in drop-down?

Comment: Hi @LeonYue, thanks for your reply, I tried to specify the key manually in the Alternate key name for both source and sink fields. In these cases, I had the  following error: `Cannot retrieve key information of alternate key 'emailaddress1' for entity 'contact'...`

Answer (score 0):

If your source is a SQL query, you can add "NewID() as ID" to your query.   Then map ID to unique identifier column.

NewId() is specific to Azure SQL and Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I received [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/36657/adf-v2-define-keys-for-upsert-behavior.html) in Microsoft Q&A.

The idea is that we need to define an alternate key on the Dynamics side. Once this is done the key will be showed on the options.

Thanks